# Unable to configure Self hosted agent on Azure DevOps in MacOs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to install azure Devops self hosted agent on my MacBook but I am having some trouble doing this. Followed the below url for configration

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops

After downloading the vets-agent tar file when I run the command its throwing error. Can someone help me?

[image: error in the terminal]

Comment: Are you running ARM? I tried to do this on ARM about two months ago and it was not supported. I then reverted to Docker, and I run my self hosted agent as as azure container instances. These are all build using docker.

Comment: no, i did not try on ARM I was trying to install an agent on my os but it has some issues. On windows, I had done this 3-4months back and was smooth. how did u use docker and implement this? Can u give me some lead it would be helpful

Comment: @Jason This is a much more basic problem: `tar` is failing to expand the tar file.

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar Please do not provide screenshots of error messages; post the actual error text.

Comment: Hi sidharth vijayakumar; can I make a suggestion? Your question would be improved if, instead of using a screenshot, you copied and pasted the actual text from the terminal into the question. It helps with readability, indexability, etc.

Answer (score 2):

When you receive error messages, please *carefully* read them; they often contain all of the relevant information you need to solve the problem on your own.

In this case, careful reading shows that you have a file named `xxx.tar`. You are running the `tar` command and pointing it to `xxx.tar.gz`. Thus, it's giving you a file not found error, which is absolutely correct, because there is no file with the `.gz` extension.